# How to create .ics file programmatically?

Tags: vb.net, icalendar

How can I create an icalendar file with minimum data, I try to make it as the following but somethings wrong, when I try to import to my Google calendar, it says Events successfully imported but I cant see those event on my calendar

```
    strResult.Append("BEGIN:VCALENDAR" & vbCrLf)           

    strResult.Append("VERSION:2.0" & vbCrLf)

    strResult.Append("METHOD:PUBLISH" & vbCrLf)

    While rst1.Read
        strResult.Append("BEGIN:VEVENT" & vbCrLf)

        strResult.Append("DTSTART: " & CDate(getLeave_date_start(CStr(rst1.getInteger("inq_id")), g_dom_id)).ToUniversalTime().ToString("yyyyMMddTHHmmssZ") & vbCrLf)    

        strResult.Append("DTEND: " & CDate(getLeave_date_end(CStr(rst1.getInteger("inq_id")), g_dom_id)).ToUniversalTime().ToString("yyyyMMddTHHmmssZ") & vbCrLf)

        strResult.Append("SUMMARY: " & rst1.getString("inq_name") & vbCrLf)

        strResult.Append("UID: " & rst1.getInteger("inq_id") & vbCrLf)

        strResult.Append("CLASS:PUBLIC" & vbCrLf)

        strResult.Append("END:VEVENT" & vbCrLf)

    End While
    strResult.Append("END:VCALENDAR" & vbCrLf)

    WriteCalendar(strResult)
```

I wrote a function WriteCalendar as follows

```
Private Sub WriteCalendar(ByVal data As String)
    Dim response As HttpResponse = Page.Response
    response.Clear()
    response.Buffer = True
    response.ContentType = "text/calendar"
    response.ContentEncoding = Encoding.UTF8
    response.Charset = "utf-8"
    response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=""" & "icalendarTest" & ".ics""")
    response.Write(data)
    response.[End]()
End Sub
```

I download the file and see my events but when it comes to importing to Google Calendar, it says 6 events imported successfully but I cant see them on my calendar

The output icalendarTest.ics

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR  
VERSION:2.0  
METHOD:PUBLISH  
BEGIN:VEVENT  
DTSTART: 20110107T060000Z  
DTEND: 20110109T080000Z  
SUMMARY: ayin yedisinden dokuzuna  
UID: 9  
CLASS:PUBLIC  
END:VEVENT  
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTART: 20110119T103000Z  
DTEND: 20110119T150000Z  
SUMMARY: tek gunluk ondokuz  
UID: 10  
CLASS:PUBLIC  
END:VEVENT  
BEGIN:VEVENT  
DTSTART: 20110213T080000Z  
DTEND: 20110213T160000Z  
SUMMARY: Mijn Event  
UID: 21  
CLASS:PUBLIC  
END:VEVENT  
BEGIN:VEVENT  
DTSTART: 20110301T083000Z  
DTEND: 20110302T110000Z  
SUMMARY: Mart kapidan baktirir  
UID: 26  
CLASS:PUBLIC  
END:VEVENT  
BEGIN:VEVENT  
DTSTART: 20110117T080000Z  
DTEND: 20110117T120000Z  
SUMMARY: Neyse bi oncesi olsun  
UID: 27  
CLASS:PUBLIC  
END:VEVENT  
BEGIN:VEVENT  
DTSTART: 20110121T130000Z  
DTEND: 20110121T180000Z  
SUMMARY: ocak 21i  
UID: 31  
CLASS:PUBLIC  
END:VEVENT  
END:VCALENDAR
```

Comment: one note: UID should be unique in the ENTIRE universe (considering all the galaxies). an integer is not a very good choice for this

Comment: can that be the reason for not showing my events?

Comment: I made another one with Guid as UID but same result, import successfull but no events showing on the calendar    BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
METHOD:PUBLISH
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTART: 20110114T230000Z
DTEND: 20110114T230000Z
SUMMARY: custom holiday
UID: 01c09e35-0bf4-4765-8489-5a07b6f3e49e
CLASS:PUBLIC
END:VEVENT
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTART: 20110429T220000Z
DTEND: 20110506T220000Z
SUMMARY: Mei vakantie
UID: bd3aa376-8743-4aaa-b486-c91f38aae540
CLASS:PUBLIC
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did not include all of the tags in .ics, thats the reason of this fault.

I extracted my own calendar from Google Calendar and include the missing data, now it works. DTSTAMP seems required though I find that uncesessary, but fine as long as it works

```
    strResult.Append("BEGIN:VCALENDAR" & vbCrLf)
    strResult.Append("PRODID:-//Google Inc//Google Calendar 70.9054//EN" & vbCrLf)
    strResult.Append("VERSION:2.0" & vbCrLf)
    strResult.Append("METHOD:PUBLISH" & vbCrLf)

    While rst1.Read
        strResult.Append("BEGIN:VEVENT" & vbCrLf)
        strResult.Append("DTSTART:" & rst1.getDateTime("hly_startdate").ToUniversalTime().ToString("yyyyMMddTHHmmssZ") & vbCrLf)
        strResult.Append("DTEND:" & rst1.getDateTime("hly_enddate").ToUniversalTime().ToString("yyyyMMddTHHmmssZ") & vbCrLf)
        strResult.Append("DTSTAMP:" & rst1.getDateTime("hly_date_created").ToUniversalTime().ToString("yyyyMMddTHHmmssZ") & vbCrLf)
        strResult.Append("SEQUENCE:0" & vbCrLf)
        strResult.Append("STATUS:CONFIRMED" & vbCrLf)
        strResult.Append("SUMMARY:" & rst1.getString("hly_name") & vbCrLf)
        strResult.Append("UID:" & System.Guid.NewGuid.ToString() & vbCrLf)
        strResult.Append("CLASS:PUBLIC" & vbCrLf)
        strResult.Append("TRANSP:OPAQUE" & vbCrLf)
        strResult.Append("END:VEVENT" & vbCrLf)

    End While
    strResult.Append("END:VCALENDAR" & vbCrLf)
```

Comment: There should not be any spaces i.e. "SEQUENCE:0". If we write this as "SEQUENCE: 0" then it is wrong

Comment: Have you found that you cannot update an existing calendar item using `METHOD:PUBLISH` no matter if you change the `SEQUENCE` and `DTSTAMP`?