# Get description from iCal occurence

Tags: c#, icalendar

I want to get the description of a free-day from a List of  items. The calendars collection is loaded from a filepath. The file is an *.ics-file. 
Everything works fine, but i cannot find out how to get the description. In the ics-File there is a name for every day, written under "SUMMARY;LANGUAGE" - node. But this is not accessable per code, or I simply cannot find it.

```
        iCal.IICalendarCollection calendars = 
        iCal.iCalendar.LoadFromFile(icsFilePath);
        IList<iCal.Occurrence> occ = 
        calendars.GetOccurrences(DateTime.MinValue, DateTime.MaxValue);

        List<Feiertag> days = new List<Feiertag>();
        foreach (Occurrence item in occ)
        {
            if (item.Period.StartTime.Date.Year == 2014)
            {
                MyClass frday = new MyClass();
                frday.Datum = item.Period.StartTime.Date;

                //item.Period.Language = null
                frday.Bezeichnung = item.Period.Language;
                days.Add(frday);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Please post an excerpt from your ics file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved it with **calendar events**

```
List<DayClass> days = new List<DayClass>();

        IICalendar cal = iCal.iCalendar.LoadFromFile(icsFilePfad).FirstOrDefault();
        if (cal != null)
        {
            foreach (var even in cal.Events)
                days.Add(new DayClass(even.Start.Date, even.Description));
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You might be looking for `PidTagSubject`, taken from [this example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee160658%28v=exchg.80%29.aspx).
In the output you can see that it translates to: `SUMMARY;LANGUAGE=en-us:Lunch`

Otherwise, what you are trying to do [might not be possible](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/49f12aff-1f6d-46ba-8e67-7d9f7ea81c1c/how-can-i-get-ics-icalendar-values-in-outlook-using-cnet-?forum=outlookdev).

Comment: I dont know what to do with that PidTagSubject, do you have an example how to use that protocoll? But to give you a better point of view, I'm trying to load a *.ics - file into the ICalendar class. My method returns a List with a "holder-class" (DateTime and Description). The holder class should just be filled with free-days. So every free day has a name.

Comment: @user3698577 Have you seen [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4933570/2596334)? it might help...